# Does setting a string char to null cause a memory leak in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, memory, memory-leaks

This seems like a silly question, but I couldn't find the answer.

Anyways, if you set an arbitrary character to null in a string,
then free the string, does that cause a memory leak?

I suppose my knowledge of how the free function works is limited.

```
/*
     char *
     strchr(const char *s, int c);

     char *
     strrchr(const char *s, int c);

     The strchr() function locates the first occurrence of c (converted to a
     char) in the string pointed to by s.  The terminating null character is
     considered part of the string; therefore if c is ‘\0’, the functions
     locate the terminating ‘\0’.

     The strrchr() function is identical to strchr() except it locates the
     last occurrence of c.
*/

char* string = strdup ("THIS IS, A STRING WITH, COMMAS!");

char* ch = strrchr( string, ',' );
*ch = 0;

free( string );

/*
    The resulting string should be: "THIS IS, A STRING WITH"
    When the string pointer is freed, does this result in a memory leak?
*/
```

Comment: I suspect it doesn't because the malloc, realloc, and free functions are based off of memory allocation rather than the contents of the memory.

Although, I really do not know.

Comment: There is no memory leak here. As you suggest, the *contents* of the memory don't matter, and the memory-manager (used by malloc, strdup and free) keeps its own track of allocated blocks, their addresses and sizes.

Comment: No it doesnt, because the size of the allocated memory is not determined by the length of the string. The allocator keeps track of every allocated block of memory and its size. If you read the man-page of `strdup`, you'll find that there is something called `malloc`, this is the allocation function, you can read malloc's manpage if you are interested in learing how to use it and maybe you can learn how it works.

Comment: If accessing the allocated memory block was causing a memory leak, then the whole `malloc` thing would be rather useless.

Comment: I used strdup to cut down on the size of the example code, strdup implies a malloc.

"the memory-manager (used by malloc, strdup and free) keeps its own track of allocated blocks" ~ This answers my question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a stupid question in my opinion.
TLDR: no you do not cause a memory leak.

Now the longer answer: `free` has no idea what a string is. If you pass it a char* or an int* it could not care less.

The way malloc and free works is the following: when you call malloc you supply a size and receive a pointer with the promise of that many bytes being reserved on the heap from the position of the pointer onwards. However at that point the size and position are also saved internally in some way (this depends and is an implementation detail).
Now when you call free it does not need to know the size, it can just remove the entry your pointer belongs to together with the size

Addendum: also not every char* points to a string, it just so happens that "abcd" becomes a null terminated char* pointing to the `'a'`, but a char* itself points to a single char, not multiple

Comment: All correct.  And you cemented a +1 by correct use of "could *not* care less" :-).

Comment: "the size and position are also saved internally in some way (this depends and is an implementation detail). Now when you call free it does not need to know the size, it can just remove the entry your pointer belongs to together with the size"  

This is exactly what I needed to know.  There's some sort of internal mapping of pointer addresses to number of bytes allocated, which the free function accesses.

Comment: DownloadPizza, "also not every char* is a string" is more like "also not every char* points to a string".  (pointers are not arrays.  arrays are not pointers.  A _string_ is more like an array.  A _string_ is not a pointer)

Comment: @BostonBSD tbf thats also an implementation detail  there is lots of heap management algorithms, but most just save a mapping of pointer to size

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Hmm, a string is a series of characters. Yes I think you are correct. Editing (im from Java land where the `String` is a reference, but its more that I just didnt think about it too hard here)

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` only allocates the chunk of memory and gives you the reference to it. If you do not ***read or write outside the boundaries of this chunk*** you can do whatever you want with it.